# Can't delete backend service in GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to free up some backend services quotas.  In order to do so, I believe I first have to delete the instance group.  However, when I tried to delete the instance group that uses the service, I get the following message:

> The deletion of the instance group failed. Error: An unknown error has
>   occurred in Compute Engine: "undefined". Error code: "undefined"

I have also tried to just delete the backend service but it will spring up another one.  In addition, I have tried to delete the load balancer associating the service and that fail also.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it was because the region. You probably are mixing a global resouce with a regional resource. Possible workarounds:

```
gcloud compute backend-services remove-backend my-backend-service
--instance-group=my-instance-group --global

gcloud compute backend-services remove-backend my-backend-service
--instance-group=my-instance-group --region=us-east1-b (other region)
```

ref: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/remove-backend

Comment: I had to fidget with this command a bit, but did get it to work, ultimately having to select a zone via interactive prompt. `gcloud compute backend-services describe my-backend-service` also proved helpful in the effort.

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#delete_backend_services):

> "To delete a backend service, you must first make sure that the backend service is not being referenced by any URL maps. If a URL map is currently referencing a backend service, you must delete the URL map to remove the reference."